# ES Lint is showing error for node_modules

Tags: node.js, eslint, hls.js

I am using rollup as build tool. All the eslint-plugins I am using are installed  locally into my folder.
The error I am getting is

```
[!] (plugin eslint) Error: Failed to load config "standard" to extend from.
Referenced from: /home/user/Projects/spl/node_modules/hls.js/.eslintrc.js
```

If I install this into my folder it works fine.
But my question is why do I need to install eslint standards for my node_modules dependencies ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am on eslint 6.8.0

Comment: is node_mdules added to your `.gitignore` or `eslintignore `? if not add it please

Comment: Already added it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I deleted .eslintrc from node_modules/hls.js and it worked

Comment: @DevangNaghera You should not do that :P